# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Texture' to 'UnityEngine.Texture2D'

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I need to grab the source image that's on a material. It happens to be texture 2D. However, when I compile code similar to below, I get the following error:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Texture' to
> 'UnityEngine.Texture2D'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
> missing a cast?)

What am I doing wrong?

```
Texture2D example;

public void Execute()
{
    MeshRenderer exampleRend = GameObject.Find("Object").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

    example = sourceRenderer.material.mainTexture = example_Source;
}
```

Comment: Did you try casting as the error suggests?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried it like this and got the same error.

example = sourceRenderer.material.mainTexture = example_Source as Texture2D;

Comment: @RetiredNinja I figured out a way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I just declared it as a Texture in my method and then converted it to Texture2D.

```
    Texture example = exampleRend.material.mainTexture = example_Source;

    Texture2D example = (Texture2D)example;
```